# using OpenCV 2.4 loading an image in MFC SDI View or Control

Tags: c++, opencv, mfc, controls

In old version of opencv we had the class like CvvImage, that were easily used for MFC controls to display camera images or simple images from the OpenCV. But in 2.4 or 2.3 this support is finished by the OpenCV , i wonder if we have any other class in new version.

My application is MFC SDI and inside view i am over riding the OnPaint function. In previous opencv i was using Paint function like

```
void CRightCameraView::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting
    m_CVvimageObj.CopyOf(m_iplImageFrame); //copy IplImage frame

    if(m_bImageDisplay)
    {
    m_CVvimageObj.Show(dc.GetSafeHdc(),10,0,m_CVvimageObj.Width(),m_CVvimageObj.Height());
    }


}
```

Kindly guide me which is the most update version of class to do same thing and support such DC controls of MFC.

Comment: What did you get when you ran your code?

Comment: this code is old one which had this cvvimage option. i want to know what should i use in new opencv 2.4. for the same functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since i could not find the answer i would like to help others what i did.

I have extracted cvvimage class manually and added in my project and then i did the following ..

in my views header file i declared

```
CvvImage m_CVvImageObj;
cv::Mat m_matImage;
```

inside my CPP file of view , i have called following in initialization function

```
m_matImage = cv::imread(strA.GetBuffer(),CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);   // Read the file

if(! m_matImage.data )                              // Check for invalid input
{
    AfxMessageBox(L"Could not open or find the image");
}


 IplImage iplimg = m_matImage;
 m_CVvImageObj.CopyOf(&iplimg);
 UpdateData();
 Invalidate();
```

inside the overided function of OnPaint inside view i added

```
if(m_CVvImageObj.GetImage())
{       
    //m_CurrentFrame.Show
        m_CVvImageObj.Show(dc.GetSafeHdc(),10,0,m_CVvImageObj.Width(),m_CVvImageObj.Height());
}
```

Cvvimage h  file is the following

```
#pragma once

//#pragma once  
#ifndef CVVIMAGE_CLASS_DEF  
#define CVVIMAGE_CLASS_DEF  

#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>    
class CvvImage  
{  
public:  
    CvvImage();  
    virtual ~CvvImage();  

    virtual bool Create( int width, int height, int bits_per_pixel, int image_origin = 0 );  
    virtual bool Load( const char* filename, int desired_color = 1 );  
    virtual bool LoadRect( const char* filename,  

    int desired_color, CvRect r );  

#if defined WIN32 || defined _WIN32  
    virtual bool LoadRect( const char* filename,int desired_color, RECT r )  
    {  
        return LoadRect( filename, desired_color,  
            cvRect( r.left, r.top, r.right - r.left, r.bottom - r.top ));  
    }  
#endif  

    virtual bool Save( const char* filename );  
    virtual void CopyOf( CvvImage& image, int desired_color = -1 );  
    virtual void CopyOf( IplImage* img, int desired_color = -1 );  
    IplImage* GetImage() { return m_img; };  
    virtual void Destroy(void);  
    int Width() { return !m_img ? 0 : !m_img->roi ? m_img->width : m_img->roi->width; };  
    int Height() { return !m_img ? 0 : !m_img->roi ? m_img->height : m_img->roi->height;};  
    int Bpp() { return m_img ? (m_img->depth & 255)*m_img->nChannels : 0; };  
    virtual void Fill( int color );  
    virtual void Show( const char* window );  

#if defined WIN32 || defined _WIN32  
    virtual void Show( HDC dc, int x, int y, int width, int height,  
        int from_x = 0, int from_y = 0 );  
    virtual void DrawToHDC( HDC hDCDst, RECT* pDstRect );  
    virtual void DrawToHDC( HDC hDCDst, CvRect pDstRect ); 
#endif  

protected:

    IplImage* m_img;

};

typedef CvvImage CImage;

#endif
```

and CPP file for cvvimage class is following

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//CvvImage.cpp

#include "StdAfx.h"  
#include "CvvImage.h"
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

CV_INLINE RECT NormalizeRect( RECT r );
CV_INLINE RECT NormalizeRect( RECT r )
{
    int t;
    if( r.left > r.right )
    {
        t = r.left;
        r.left = r.right;
        r.right = t;
    }
    if( r.top > r.bottom )
    {
        t = r.top;
        r.top = r.bottom;
        r.bottom = t;
    }

    return r;
}
CV_INLINE CvRect RectToCvRect( RECT sr );
CV_INLINE CvRect RectToCvRect( RECT sr )
{
    sr = NormalizeRect( sr );
    return cvRect( sr.left, sr.top, sr.right - sr.left, sr.bottom - sr.top );
}
CV_INLINE RECT CvRectToRect( CvRect sr );
CV_INLINE RECT CvRectToRect( CvRect sr )
{
    RECT dr;
    dr.left = sr.x;
    dr.top = sr.y;
    dr.right = sr.x + sr.width;
    dr.bottom = sr.y + sr.height;

    return dr;
}
CV_INLINE IplROI RectToROI( RECT r );
CV_INLINE IplROI RectToROI( RECT r )
{
    IplROI roi;
    r = NormalizeRect( r );
    roi.xOffset = r.left;
    roi.yOffset = r.top;
    roi.width = r.right - r.left;
    roi.height = r.bottom - r.top;
    roi.coi = 0;

    return roi;
}
void FillBitmapInfo( BITMAPINFO* bmi, int width, int height, int bpp, int origin )
{
    assert( bmi && width >= 0 && height >= 0 && (bpp == 8 || bpp == 24 || bpp == 32));

    BITMAPINFOHEADER* bmih = &(bmi->bmiHeader);

    memset( bmih, 0, sizeof(*bmih));
    bmih->biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bmih->biWidth = width;
    bmih->biHeight = origin ? abs(height) : -abs(height);
    bmih->biPlanes = 1;
    bmih->biBitCount = (unsigned short)bpp;
    bmih->biCompression = BI_RGB;
    if( bpp == 8 )
    {
        RGBQUAD* palette = bmi->bmiColors;
        int i;
        for( i = 0; i < 256; i++ )
        {
            palette[i].rgbBlue = palette[i].rgbGreen = palette[i].rgbRed = (BYTE)i;
            palette[i].rgbReserved = 0;
        }
    }
}
CvvImage::CvvImage()
{
    m_img = 0;
}
void CvvImage::Destroy()
{
    cvReleaseImage( &m_img );
}
CvvImage::~CvvImage()
{
    Destroy();
}
bool CvvImage::Create( int w, int h, int bpp, int origin )
{
    const unsigned max_img_size = 10000;

    if( (bpp != 8 && bpp != 24 && bpp != 32) ||
        (unsigned)w >= max_img_size || (unsigned)h >= max_img_size ||
        (origin != IPL_ORIGIN_TL && origin != IPL_ORIGIN_BL))
    {
        assert(0); // most probably, it is a programming error
        return false;
    }
    if( !m_img || Bpp() != bpp || m_img->width != w || m_img->height != h )
    {
        if( m_img && m_img->nSize == sizeof(IplImage))
            Destroy();

        m_img = cvCreateImage( cvSize( w, h ), IPL_DEPTH_8U, bpp/8 );
    }
    if( m_img )
        m_img->origin = origin == 0 ? IPL_ORIGIN_TL : IPL_ORIGIN_BL;
    return m_img != 0;
}
void CvvImage::CopyOf( CvvImage& image, int desired_color )
{
    IplImage* img = image.GetImage();
    if( img )
    {
        CopyOf( img, desired_color );
    }
}
#define HG_IS_IMAGE(img) \
    ((img) != 0 && ((const IplImage*)(img))->nSize == sizeof(IplImage) && \
    ((IplImage*)img)->imageData != 0)
void CvvImage::CopyOf( IplImage* img, int desired_color )
{
    if( HG_IS_IMAGE(img) )
    {
        int color = desired_color;
        CvSize size = cvGetSize( img ); 
        if( color < 0 )
            color = img->nChannels > 1;
        if( Create( size.width, size.height,
            (!color ? 1 : img->nChannels > 1 ? img->nChannels : 3)*8,
            img->origin ))
        {
            cvConvertImage( img, m_img, 0 );
        }
    }
}
bool CvvImage::Load( const char* filename, int desired_color )
{
    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage( filename, desired_color );
    if( !img )
        return false;

    CopyOf( img, desired_color );
    cvReleaseImage( &img );

    return true;
}
bool CvvImage::LoadRect( const char* filename,
                        int desired_color, CvRect r )
{
    if( r.width < 0 || r.height < 0 ) return false;


    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage( filename, desired_color );
    if( !img )
        return false;
    if( r.width == 0 || r.height == 0 )
    {
        r.width = img->width;
        r.height = img->height;
        r.x = r.y = 0;
    }
    if( r.x > img->width || r.y > img->height ||
        r.x + r.width < 0 || r.y + r.height < 0 )
    {
        cvReleaseImage( &img );
        return false;
    }

    if( r.x < 0 )
    {
        r.width += r.x;
        r.x = 0;
    }
    if( r.y < 0 )
    {
        r.height += r.y;
        r.y = 0;
    }
    if( r.x + r.width > img->width )
        r.width = img->width - r.x;

    if( r.y + r.height > img->height )
        r.height = img->height - r.y;
    cvSetImageROI( img, r );
    CopyOf( img, desired_color );
    cvReleaseImage( &img );
    return true;
}
bool CvvImage::Save( const char* filename )
{
    if( !m_img )
        return false;
    cvSaveImage( filename, m_img );
    return true;
}
void CvvImage::Show( const char* window )
{
    if( m_img )
        cvShowImage( window, m_img );
}
void CvvImage::Show( HDC dc, int x, int y, int w, int h, int from_x, int from_y )
{
    if( m_img && m_img->depth == IPL_DEPTH_8U )
    {
        uchar buffer[sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + 1024];
        BITMAPINFO* bmi = (BITMAPINFO*)buffer;
        int bmp_w = m_img->width, bmp_h = m_img->height;
        FillBitmapInfo( bmi, bmp_w, bmp_h, Bpp(), m_img->origin );
        from_x = MIN( MAX( from_x, 0 ), bmp_w - 1 );
        from_y = MIN( MAX( from_y, 0 ), bmp_h - 1 );
        int sw = MAX( MIN( bmp_w - from_x, w ), 0 );
        int sh = MAX( MIN( bmp_h - from_y, h ), 0 );
        SetDIBitsToDevice(
            dc, x, y, sw, sh, from_x, from_y, from_y, sh,
            m_img->imageData + from_y*m_img->widthStep,
            bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS );
    }
}
void CvvImage::DrawToHDC( HDC hDCDst, RECT* pDstRect ) 
{
    if( pDstRect && m_img && m_img->depth == IPL_DEPTH_8U && m_img->imageData )
    {
        uchar buffer[sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + 1024];
        BITMAPINFO* bmi = (BITMAPINFO*)buffer;
        int bmp_w = m_img->width, bmp_h = m_img->height;
        CvRect roi = cvGetImageROI( m_img );
        CvRect dst = RectToCvRect( *pDstRect );
        if( roi.width == dst.width && roi.height == dst.height )
        {
            Show( hDCDst, dst.x, dst.y, dst.width, dst.height, roi.x, roi.y );
            return;
        }
        if( roi.width > dst.width )
        {
            SetStretchBltMode(
                hDCDst, // handle to device context
                HALFTONE );
        }
        else
        {
            SetStretchBltMode(
                hDCDst, // handle to device context
                COLORONCOLOR );
        }
        FillBitmapInfo( bmi, bmp_w, bmp_h, Bpp(), m_img->origin );
        ::StretchDIBits(hDCDst,dst.x, dst.y, dst.width, dst.height,roi.x, roi.y, roi.width, roi.height,\
            m_img->imageData, bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, SRCCOPY );
    }
}
void CvvImage::DrawToHDC( HDC hDCDst, CvRect pDstRect )
{
    RECT rDest=CvRectToRect(pDstRect);
    DrawToHDC(hDCDst,&rDest);
}
void CvvImage::Fill( int color )
{
    cvSet( m_img, cvScalar(color&255,(color>>8)&255,(color>>16)&255,(color>>24)&255) );
}
```

enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

1.first load a picture get pic name and path.

```
void CvlistDlg::OnBnClickedRead()
{
    CString     FilePathName;
    CString     FileName;
    CFileDialog openVideo(true);
    openVideo.m_ofn.lpstrTitle = _T("Open");
    if (IDOK == openVideo.DoModal()){
        FileName = openVideo.GetFileName();
        FilePathName = openVideo.GetPathName();
        _currentFile._fileName = FileName;
        _currentFile._filePath = FilePathName;
    }
 }
```

2.add follow code in your button callback function.

```
void CvlistDlg::OnBnClickedOk(){
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread(str);
    CDC *pDC = GetDlgItem(IDC_Pic)->GetDC();
    HDC hDC = pDC->GetSafeHdc();
    CRect rect;
    GetDlgItem(IDC_Pic)->GetClientRect(&rect);
    int rw = rect.right - rect.left;     //the width of your picture control
    int rh = rect.bottom - rect.top;
    if (!img.data){
        MessageBox(_T("read picture fail！"));
        return;
    }
    cv::resize(img, img, cv::Size(rw, rh));     
    IplImage iplimg = img;
    m_CVvImageObj.CopyOf(&iplimg);
    UpdateData();
    if (m_CVvImageObj.GetImage()){
        m_CVvImageObj.Show(pDC->GetSafeHdc(), 0, 0, rw, rh);
    }
}
```

I hope those can give you some help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need of IplImage. Basically you can draw a cv::Mat to a DC of a MFC control, using StretchDIBits.
It accepts pointer to memory block where the bitmap is stored... in this case cv::Mat.data

But remember that (this make me crazing before)

- GDI requires DWORD alignment while cv::Mat don't use any rows padding
- In addition your Mat could be a ROI this means that at the end each rows there isn't next row but the image that continues

You can have DWORD alignment in OpenCV using images where cols % 4 == 0 so you can add a border to your image

```
  border = 4 - (img.cols % 4);
  if ( (border<4 && border > 0) || img.isContinuous() == false)
  {
    cv::copyMakeBorder(img, tmpImg, 0, 0, 0, border, cv::BORDER_CONSTANT, 0);
  }
  else
    tmpImg = img
```

Using copyMakeBorder you will solve both requirements

Another issues is grey images because MFC requires a flat palette to display it. You can convert your Mat with cvtColor or create the palette:

```
   uchar buffer[sizeof(BITMAPINFO) + 1024];
   BITMAPINFO* bmi = (BITMAPINFO*)buffer;
   BITMAPINFOHEADER* bmih = &(bmi->bmiHeader);
   bmih->biBitCount = 8*img.elemenSize()
   bmih->biWidth = tmpImg.cols;
   bmih->biHeight = -tmpImg.rows;// DIB are bottom ->top
   bmih->...

  //The palette is required for grey image
  if (bmih->biBitCount == 8)
  {
    RGBQUAD* palette = bmi->bmiColors;
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
      palette[i].rgbBlue = palette[i].rgbGreen = palette[i].rgbRed = (BYTE)i;
      palette[i].rgbReserved = 0;
    }
  }
```

finally draw to HDC

```
imgH = img.rows;
imgW = img.cols; //use original cols  to avoid border

ClientDC hDC(WinCtrl);

//rr is relative to control
RECT rr; WinCtrl->GetClientRect(&rr);  

StretchDIBits(hDC,
  0, 0, rr.right, rr.bottom,
  0, 0, imgW, imgH,
  tmpImg.data, bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, SRCCOPY);
```

You can find detailed info and a class to manage image fitting here:
http://www.pklab.net/?&id=390&lang=EN&t=How-to-display-an-OpenCV-image-or-video-in-your-own-MFC-interface