# OpenCV 2.4 : Displaying a cv::Mat in MFC

Tags: c++, opencv, mfc

I am updating an existing code base from IplImage* to the newer cv::Mat. I was wondering how to display my cv::Mat object to MFC. The current solution we are using is based on the old CvvImage class:

```cpp
void DrawPicToHDC(IplImage *img, UINT ID, bool bOnPaint)
{
    CDC *pDC = GetDlgItem(ID)->GetDC();
    HDC hDC= pDC->GetSafeHdc();
    CRect rect;
    GetDlgItem(ID)->GetClientRect(&rect);
    CvvImage cimg;
    cimg.CopyOf( img );
    cimg.DrawToHDC( hDC, &rect );
    ReleaseDC( pDC );
}
```

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12891307/using-opencv-2-4-loading-an-image-in-mfc-sdi-view-or-control) thread but unfortunately the answer provided doesn't meet my needs because the answers still require you to convert the Mat to an IplImage* before displaying.

Is there any way to do this using cv::Mat only? Any help is much appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
I adapted the above function to using cv::Mat with the help from Kornel's answer. I now do not need to include the CvvImage class:

```cpp
void DrawPicToHDC(cv::Mat cvImg, UINT ID, bool bOnPaint)
{
    // Get the HDC handle information from the ID passed
    CDC *pDC = GetDlgItem(ID)->GetDC();
    HDC hDCDst = pDC->GetSafeHdc();
    CRect rect;
    GetDlgItem(ID)->GetClientRect(&rect);
    cv::Size winSize(rect.right, rect.bottom);

    // Resize the source to the size of the destination image if necessary
    cv::Mat cvImgTmp(winSize, CV_8UC3);
    if (cvImg.size() != winSize)
    {
        cv::resize(cvImg, cvImgTmp, winSize);
    }
    else
    {
        cvImgTmp = cvImg;
    }

    // Rotate the image
    cv::flip(cvImgTmp,cvImgTmp,0);

    // Initialize the BITMAPINFO structure
    BITMAPINFO bitInfo;
    bitInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 24;
    bitInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth = winSize.width;
    bitInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight = winSize.height;
    bitInfo.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bitInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bitInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bitInfo.bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;
    bitInfo.bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
    bitInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = 0;
    bitInfo.bmiHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bitInfo.bmiHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;

    // Add header and OPENCV image's data to the HDC
    StretchDIBits(hDCDst, 0, 0,
        winSize.width, winSize.height, 0, 0,
        winSize.width, winSize.height,
        cvImgTmp.data, &bitInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS, SRCCOPY);

    ReleaseDC( pDC );
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose we have an OpenCV image `cv::Mat cvImg` which one should be converted to `CImage* mfcImg`.
Of course the MFC image should be displayed on an MFC window i.e. in `CStatic winImg`

So the following transformations should be performed in order to display an OpenCV image in an MFC window:

```
cv::Mat -> CImage -> CStatic
```

Define MFC window size:

```
RECT r;
winImg.GetClientRect(&r);
cv::Size winSize(r.right, r.bottom);
```

The size of `cvImg` is not always the same as an MFC window’s:

```
cv::Mat cvImgTmp(winSize, CV_8UC3);
if (cvImg.size() != winSize)
{
    cv::resize(cvImg, cvImgTmp, winSize);
}
else 
{
    cvImgTmp = cvImg.clone();
}
```

Rotate the image:

```
cv::flip(cvImgTmp, cvImgTmp, 0);
```

Create an MFC image:

```
if (mfcImg)
{
    mfcImg->ReleaseDC();
    delete mfcImg; mfcImg = nullptr;
}

mfcImg = new CImage();
mfcImg->Create(winSize.width, winSize.height, 24);
```

For `mfcImg` you need a header. Create it by using `BITMAPINFO` structure

```
BITMAPINFO bitInfo;
bitInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 24;
bitInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth = winSize.width;
bitInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight = winSize.height;
bitInfo.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
bitInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
bitInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
bitInfo.bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;
bitInfo.bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
bitInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = 0;
bitInfo.bmiHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
bitInfo.bmiHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
```

Add header and OpenCV image’s data to `mfcImg`

```
StretchDIBits(mfcImg->GetDC(), 0, 0,
    winSize.width, winSize.height, 0, 0,
    winSize.width, winSize.height,
    cvImgTmp.data, &bitInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS, SRCCOPY
);
```

Display `mfcImg` in MFC window

```
mfcImg->BitBlt(::GetDC(winImg.m_hWnd), 0, 0);
```

Release `mfcImg`, if you will not use it:

```
if (mfcImg)
{
    mfcImg->ReleaseDC();
    delete mfcImg; mfcImg = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer, the step-by-step explanations were just what I needed! Will also upvote when I get more reputation points