# How to output cv::Mat in MFC window

Tags: c++, opencv, mfc

I have 2 programs, MFC program and OpenCV. How I should to unite programs?
How output cv::Mat in MFC window? What MFC widget I should be use? How I should convert cv::Mat to MFC widgets?

**MFC program:**

```
#include <afxwin.h> 

        class CMyMainWnd : public CFrameWnd
        {
        public:
            CMyMainWnd() { Create(NULL, L"My title"); }
        };

        class CMyApp : public CWinApp
        {
        public:
            CMyApp() {};
            virtual BOOL InitInstance() {
                m_pMainWnd = new CMyMainWnd();
                m_pMainWnd->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
                return TRUE;
            }
        };

        CMyApp theApp;
```

**OpenCV program:**

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main() {

    VideoCapture cap(0);

    while (1) {

        Mat frame;
        cap >> frame;

        if (frame.empty())
            break;

        imshow("Frame", frame);

        char c = (char)waitKey(25);
        if (c == 27)
            break;
    }

    cap.release();

    destroyAllWindows();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenCV 2.4 : Displaying a cv::Mat in MFC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28997560/opencv-2-4-displaying-a-cvmat-in-mfc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `main` example differs in that it doesn't directly create any window. It lets opencv create the window.

To duplicate that example, simply move the opencv loop in to `CWinApp::InitInstance` and don't create a separate MFC window.

To unite opencv with MFC, use opencv to grab the video frame, and draw the frame on MFC window.

`CWinApp::OnIdle` can be used to continuously update the window. opencv's `frame` includes the bitmap bits, these bits can be copied directly to MFC windows's `HDC` using `SetDIBitsToDevice` or similar functions.

```
class CMyMainWnd : public CFrameWnd
{
    cv::VideoCapture video;
public:
    CMyMainWnd()
    {
        video.open(0);
    }

    void CMyMainWnd::OnPaint()
    {
        CPaintDC dc(this);

        cv::Mat mat;
        video >> mat;
        if(mat.empty())
            return;

        BITMAPINFOHEADER bi = { sizeof(bi) };
        bi.biWidth = mat.cols;
        bi.biHeight = -mat.rows;
        bi.biBitCount = (WORD)(mat.channels() * 8);
        bi.biPlanes = 1;

        SetDIBitsToDevice(dc, 0, 0, mat.cols, mat.rows, 0, 0, 0, mat.rows,
            mat.data, (BITMAPINFO*)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
    }

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyMainWnd, CWnd)
    ON_WM_PAINT()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

class CMyApp : public CWinApp
{
public:
    virtual BOOL InitInstance()
    {
        CWinApp::InitInstance();
        CMyMainWnd *wnd = new CMyMainWnd();
        m_pMainWnd = wnd;
        wnd->Create(NULL, L"My title");
        wnd->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
        return TRUE;
    }

    BOOL OnIdle(LONG lCount)
    {
        CWinApp::OnIdle(lCount);
        m_pMainWnd->Invalidate(FALSE);
        return TRUE;
    }
};

CMyApp theApp;
```